# Media Query Doesn't Work with CSS3 HTML5 on Mobile and Desktop

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a web page which needed to become responsive, a bit more.
Obviously , I changed the needed parameters in an appropriate media query. The following one is for an iPhone X:

```
@media only screen
  and (min-device-width: 375px)
  and (max-device-width: 812px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
    .carousel-inner {
      width: 300%;
    }
    .main-text {
      top: 25px;
    }
}
```

The meta viewport has been correctly added to the header to.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

But then it won't work. The media query isn't applying itself when browsing with my smartphone (iPhone X).

To precise, all the media query part is at the end of the general styling. By order it's all iPhones, from the 4th to the latest. I don't think it's an order problem, maybe an importation one ?

Here is the link tag which is placed in the header.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{SITE_URL}templates/{TPL_NAME}/assets/css/slider.css">
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What's with the `{SITE_URL}`? Are you using a framework/template engine or is that the actual folder name?

Comment: It's a kind of function returning the actual site url, but it"s working well with every other stylesheets link `{TPL_NAME}` is also a kind of function returning the name of a folder

Comment: Is your media query the very last CSS that's loaded? Just to make 100% sure it's not an "order of CSS" problem.

Comment: it is the very last file loaded

Comment: Your problem seems to be with `and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)` & `and (orientation: portrait)`. Both seem to be syntactically correct, so not sure what's up there.

Comment: I copied the media query from a website who provided it. I removed the `-` and it didn't change the result. Thanks for your help and precious time anyway

Comment: it seems to be the numerical value of `(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)` if I change it to 1 for instance, it works for me. Maybe fiddle with that. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be within your pixel density statement. Perhaps the style isn't displaying because of your device's pixel density.

The value "0.75", indicates that the styles are for devices with low pixel density.

The value "1", indicates that the styles are for devices with a medium pixel density. (aka the laptop I'm using right now for instance).

The value "1.5" indicates a device with a high pixel density.

So it seems that your pixel density value of 3 is extraordinary high, which might be why your styles aren't displaying. Instead, try some of the other values.

Read more about the pixel density specs [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#resolution).

Comment: thanks, but the pixel density statement is correct for the iPhone X in our case

Comment: it seems that when I want to change the height of an element `<img>` it's not working. In the Chrome inspector the rule is ruled

Comment: Sorry, then there isn't enough information to go off.